# Disk partitions for Windows 7 & Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I had Windows 7 previously. I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04 along with it and installed it (from USB).

Actually, I created a separate 40GB disk partition for Ubuntu. But nowhere during the installation, it was asked on which disk you want to install.

Before I installed Ubuntu the disk was like:

```
C: primary partition for Windows
D: (Entertainment)Logical Drive
E: (Files) Logical Drive
39.64GB: Unallocated
```

After the installation there are a few changes I'm not able to understand. 
Can someone explain what has happened in the following areas?

1. `C:` it now says boot,page file, crash dump, primary partition (what do these new terms mean?)
2. `35.74GB: primary partition`
3. `3.87GB: primary partition` (which of these two actually contain Ubuntu?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "install ubuntu along side with windows" during installation then, your C drive space gets reduced and split into 35.74GB (in this partition you will have Ubutnu installed) and 3.87GB (this is for the Swap space) partitions

or if u installed ubuntu into your 39.64GB unallocated partition it split into 35.74GB(Ubutnu OS) and 3.87GB(Swap space)

for C drive showing boot=>'bootable drive' page file=>'showing your windows page file is located in C' which is not a problem

i think you installed ubutnu along side with windows thats why your C drive shows those

you can install ubuntu into seperate partition by selecting "something else" option which is below "install along side with windows" option during installation